# NPM command to drop mongo database, using "echo" not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm, echo, npm-scripts

I'm trying to create an `npm` command that drops a database from my mongo instance.

When I paste this line of code directly into my shell, it works, and gives the output below:

```
> echo 'db.dropDatabase()' | mongo musicappdb

MongoDB shell version v3.4.10
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/musicappdb
MongoDB server version: 3.4.10
{ "ok" : 1 }
bye
```

However when I run it from my npm script, which is defined like this

```
scripts: {
     ...
     "drop-db": "echo 'db.dropDatabase()' | mongo musicappdb",
     ...
  },
```

I get

```
> echo "db.dropDatabase()" | mongo musicappdb

MongoDB shell version v3.4.10
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/musicappdb
MongoDB server version: 3.4.10
db.dropDatabase()
bye
```

And the database is **NOT** getting dropped.

**Why is the command not behaving properly when I issue through npm?**

Comment: hey friend see this article maybe helps : http://antrikshy.com/blog/run-mongodb-automatically-nodejs-project

Comment: `echo 'db.dropDatabase()' | mongo musicappdb` is this command run in termial or mongoshell?

Comment: cmd terminal (Windows 8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
"drop-db": "echo db.dropDatabase() | mongo musicappdb"
```

Without the single quotes.

It didn't work with either double or single quote. This is on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

hey see this article maybe helps :

http://antrikshy.com/blog/run-mongodb-automatically-nodejs-project

just test :

`'start mongo admin --eval "db.dropDatebase()" '`

Comment: Thanks. Just tried with `mongo musicappdb --eval 'db.dropDatabase()'"` but still no luck from npm. Yet it works if I run directly in my terminal

Comment: maybe you must be admin to drop your databases

Comment: Tried as admin, didn't work. Also it works without me being admin when doing in terminal directly

Answer (score 0):

```
"drop-db": "echo 'db.dropDatabase()' | mongo myDB"
```

This worked for me

Output was

```
MongoDB shell version v4.0.9
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/myDB?gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("44d9deb8-6de1-49ff-8532-24cf2ae5247b") }
MongoDB server version: 4.0.9
{ "ok" : 1 }
bye
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone is using Docker container:

```
docker exec -it mongodb_container sh -c "mongo db_name --eval 'db.dropDatabase()'"
```